# Sabre API for discount & markup against air ticket prices

Tags: api, rest, sabre

could you please confirm that is there any API to define discount/markup on Air ticket prices? If yes please tell me the name of Sabre API.
I tried to get help from sabre documentation but I did't get exactly API against my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Sabre's documentation site? Contact your support? Are you sure you have access to that operation in the first place? Sabre's docs don't display operations you have no access to

Comment: actually I have created PNR successfully. but now I want to make muddle of discount and markup offers  for flight prices and    I have read out documentation but did't get exactly api solution

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add and enter the commission in the section shown below for the RQ.

[image]

You may refer to the RQ design documentation for reference.

https://files.developer.sabre.com/drc/servicedoc/AirTicketLLSRQ_v2.14.0_Design.xml

Hope this clarifies.